# how can I add an overlapped anchor in both overlapped paths automatically

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How I can add an anchor point for each intersected selected paths in illustrator automatically?

I know `smart Guide` and `add anchor point tool` can do the job but it will add just one anchor in the front path only. If I use pathfinder outline or the scissors my paths get cut and I have to re-join them again one by one.

[image]

Comment: trim fuction is available in hotdoor cadtools

Comment: Update: shapebuilder does this of you still need this

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed, the `Add Anchor Point` tool only adds a single point to the front-most path. After adding it to the front path though, you can select the other path, and then while it is selected, use the `Add Anchor Point` tool again. Since the back path is selected, it will be the destination of the new anchor point.

[image: Add Anchor Point]

I know it isn't automated, but at least you don't have to re-join paths after.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that in fact the `Shape Builder` has this side effect that does what you ask. When you select curves for shape building, Adobe temporarily intersects all curves that participate in the deletion. Once you commit a shape build, this 'temporary' becomes in fact fixed.

How to use? Continue the curve you want to do this; draw a line to block the effect. <kbd>Alt</kbd> shape build drag so the continuation and blocker get deleted, this will cause *all* intersections to appear on the curves.

This is a bit of a hack, but it saved me form some angst last week.

Answer (score 0):

There is no automated method I'm aware of to auto-add anchors at path intersections.

`Pathfinder > Trim` may offer an acceptable result is your paths are part of *shapes* (close paths) and not merely open paths.

Comment: yes it may be a solution for close paths but actually I am asking bout open paths. sorry I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from closing a path, using Pathfinder,then removing the portions of the closed path you don't want.

Comment: sure, I am using this method in simple and easy shapes. but this method will be impossible with complex illustrations.